# What does this system monitor readout say about my RAM?

Tags: 16.04, ram, system-monitor

My machine as has 16GB of RAM. In the Memory and Swap History pane, is the red line the amount of RAM being used? I've never seen any other display. Does this mean that I'm consistently NOT using much of my RAM?

[image: System Monitor]

Comment: "Consistently" and "not using" don't make much sense together, and the picture shows RAM usage durring 60 seconds. It is clear that not all RAM has been used. More or less RAM may have been used before or after, but we don't know that.

Comment: It currently shows that you're using 6.3G out of your 16G total RAM. However, "unused" RAM is used as a disk/file buffer, so total used RAM is actually higher (after the system has been running for a while). You can see this when viewing the `top` command in the `terminal`.

Comment: Thanks mikewhatever -- the display above is what I see all day long. I use pretty much the same programs all day, don't jump around a log.

Comment: heynnema or anyone -- I'm guessing, but I want to understand. What does the green swap line (at 0) represent? Is it the bytes written to disk (4GiB space reserved) if my unused 9.3 GiB RAM is used up? If so, does that mean that the system would be faster until the 9.3 is used up, after which it would slow down (a little?) as it writes to disk?

Answer (score 1):

The red line is indicating that you are using about 40.6% of your physical memory. So to answer your question, yes it is an indication of how much RAM the system is currently using.